# Replacing words with spaces in objective c

Tags: objective-c, replace, nsstring

i have a string like this :

`NSString *test = @"This is a test string";`

i want to replace "test" word with spaces to be like this :

"This is a      string"

how can i do such a thing?

i have tried to use this function

```
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:@"    "];
```

and didn't work fine.

Comment: What was the result given when you tried that code? It should have made test be "This is a      string"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *test = @"This is a test string";
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",test);

Use this. No need to give space. it will replace that word with empty space.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *test = @"This is a test string";
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" test" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",test);
```

it should work, hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: what is the output of the code written by me? its perfectly working on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableString instead of NSString.Repalce NSString *test = @"This is a test string" with
NSMutableString *test = @"This is a test string";